# AJAX data post in Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem in ajax posting. i try to get category when select parent category in drop down.but data is post.

my business controller

```
 public function getcat($id)
{
    echo "sdfad";
    $cr=new Categoryrepo();
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode($cr->getcatbyparentid($id)));
}
```

my category model

```
 public function getcatbyparentid($id)
{
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('parent',$id);
   return $query=$this->db->get();
}
```

my ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#parent").change(function(){
        var id=$('#parent').val();
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url()?>business/getcat/"+id,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

please help me how to solve it

Comment: Well, in your model, you aren't returning any result from DB. So, you should use `result()` or any other function from Codeigniter [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) according to your requirements. And, I really didn't get what you really need. Are you having trouble with how to populate the child dropdown list? or because returned data isn't correct??

Comment: What is the result, print it. Your question is not complete. Also show us `console` errors.

Answer (score 0):

now it working ......
Json return proper data like  [{"id":"8","name":"mobile"},{"id":"10","name":"mno`"}].

now Questions is how to bind this data  in drop down list..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Model:**

```
public function getcatbyparentid($id){
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('parent',$id);
    // just return query! In controller we will handle it.
    return $query;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->model("Categoryrepo");
$html = $this->Categoryrepo->getcatbyparentid($id);
$content  = "<select name='yourName'>";
foreach($html->result() as $row){
    $content .= '<option value="'. $row->column_name1 .'">' . $row->column_name2 . "</option>";
}
$content .= "</select>";
$result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $content);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your model function as below:

```
public function getcatbyparentid($id)
{
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $this->db->where('parent',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get('category');
    if($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->result() // or return $query->row() <if you want only one value to be return>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why my answer is counted as negative?